# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Can someone please help me figure out the reason behind this `NullPointerException`.

This is my error log:

```
8-13 23:27:33.924    4817-4817/? E/Zygote﹕ MountEmulatedStorage()
08-13 23:27:33.924    4817-4817/? E/Zygote﹕ v2
08-13 23:27:33.934    4817-4817/? E/SELinux﹕ [DEBUG] get_category: variable 
seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
08-13 23:27:34.024    4817-4817/com.kishore_kumar.call E/AndroidRuntime﹕ 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.kishore_kumar.call, PID: 4817
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo
{com.kishore_kumar.call/com.kishore_kumar.call.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual 
method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null 
object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
(ActivityThread.java:2515)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity    
(ActivityThread.java:2723)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage
(ActivityThread.java:1422)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual     
 method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null 
 object reference
        at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:2168)
        at com.kishore_kumar.call.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:21)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1650)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
 (ActivityThread.java:2505)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity  
 (ActivityThread.java:2723)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage
 (ActivityThread.java:1422)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

---

My 'MainActivity' File:

```
package com.kishore_kumar.call;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.*;

/**
* Simple one-activity app that takes a search term via the Action Bar
* and uses it as a query to search the contacts database via the Contactables
* table.
*/
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static final int CONTACT_QUERY_LOADER = 0;
    public static final String QUERY_KEY = "query";
    public EditText cn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mainEditText);
    String query = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        startQuery();
    }

    private void startQuery()
    {
        query = cn.getText().toString();
        // We need to create a bundle containing the query string to send along to the
        // LoaderManager, which will be handling querying the database and returning results.
        if(query!="")
        {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(QUERY_KEY, query);

            ContactablesLoaderCallbacks loaderCallbacks = new     
                ContactablesLoaderCallbacks(this);

            // Start the loader with the new query, and an object that will 
            handle all callbacks.
                getLoaderManager().restartLoader(CONTACT_QUERY_LOADER, bundle, 
                        loaderCallbacks);
        }
    }
}
```

---

And this is my Loader Object Class File:

```
package com.kishore_kumar.call;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
* Helper class to handle all the callbacks that occur when interacting with 
loaders.  Most of the
* interesting code in this sample app will be in this file.
*/
public class ContactablesLoaderCallbacks implements 
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    Context mContext;

    public static final String QUERY_KEY = "query";

    public static final String TAG = "CLoaderCallbacks";

    public ContactablesLoaderCallbacks(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderIndex, Bundle bundle) {
        // Where the Contactables table excels is matching text queries,
        // not just data dumps from Contacts db.  One search term is used to query
        // display name, email address and phone number.  In this case, the query was extracted
        // from an incoming intent in the handleIntent() method, via the
        // intent.getStringExtra() method.

        // BEGIN_INCLUDE(uri_with_query)
        String query = bundle.getString(QUERY_KEY);
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
            CommonDataKinds.Contactables.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, query);
        // END_INCLUDE(uri_with_query)


        // BEGIN_INCLUDE(cursor_loader)
        // Easy way to limit the query to contacts with phone numbers.
        String selection = CommonDataKinds.Contactables.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = " + 1;

        // Sort results such that rows for the same contact stay together.
        String sortBy = CommonDataKinds.Contactables.LOOKUP_KEY;

        return new CursorLoader(
            mContext,  // Context
            uri,       // URI representing the table/resource to be queried
            null,      // projection - the list of columns to return.  Null means "all"
            selection, // selection - Which rows to return (condition rows must match)
            null,      // selection args - can be provided separately and subbed into selection.
            sortBy);   // string specifying sort order
        // END_INCLUDE(cursor_loader)
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView tv  = (TextView) ((Activity)mContext).findViewById(R.id.sampleOutput);
        if(tv == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "TextView is null?!");
        } else if (mContext == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Context is null?");
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Nothing is null?!");
        }

        // Reset text in case of a previous query
        tv.setText(mContext.getText(R.string.intro) + "\n\n");

        if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        // Pulling the relevant value from the cursor requires knowing the column index to pull
        // it from.
        // BEGIN_INCLUDE(get_columns)
        int phoneColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex
        (CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
        int emailColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex
        (CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS);
        int nameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex
        (CommonDataKinds.Contactables.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int lookupColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex  
        (CommonDataKinds.Contactables.LOOKUP_KEY);
        int typeColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex
        (CommonDataKinds.Contactables.MIMETYPE);
        // END_INCLUDE(get_columns)

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        // Lookup key is the easiest way to verify a row of data is for the same
        // contact as the previous row.
        String lookupKey = "";
        do {
            // BEGIN_INCLUDE(lookup_key)
            String currentLookupKey = cursor.getString(lookupColumnIndex);
            if (!lookupKey.equals(currentLookupKey)) {
                String displayName = cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex);
                tv.append(displayName + "\n");
                lookupKey = currentLookupKey;
            }
            // END_INCLUDE(lookup_key)

            // BEGIN_INCLUDE(retrieve_data)
            // The data type can be determined using the mime type column.
            String mimeType = cursor.getString(typeColumnIndex);
            if (mimeType.equals(CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
                tv.append("\tPhone Number: " + cursor.getString
               (phoneColumnIndex) + "\n");
            } else
            {
                tv.setText("selected contact has no phone number");
            }
            // END_INCLUDE(retrieve_data)

            // Look at DDMS to see all the columns returned by a query to  Contactables.
            // Behold, the firehose!
            for(String column : cursor.getColumnNames()) {
                Log.d(TAG, column + column + ": " +
                      cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(column)) + "\n");
            }
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {
    }
}
```

This is my main layout file:

---

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="top|left"
android:orientation="vertical" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Please enter contact name:"
        android:textSize="36sp"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Contact Name"
        android:id="@+id/mainEditText"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/intro"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sampleOutput"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

Also this line in my ContactablesLoaderCallbacks file produces an error:

```
tv.setText(mContext.getText(R.string.intro) + "\n\n");
```

```
Method invocation tv.setText(mContext.getText(R.string.intro) + "\n\n")' may 
produce java.lang.NullPointerException' less... (Ctrl+F1) This inspection 
analyzes method control and data flow to report possible conditions that are 
always true or false, expressions whose value is statically proven to be 
constant, and situations that can lead to nullability contract violations. 
Variables, method parameters and return values marked as @Nullable or 
@NotNull are treated as nullable (or not-null, respectively) and used during 
the analysis to check nullability contracts, e.g. report possible munpoin 
terException errors. 
More complex contracts can be defined using @contract annotation, for     
example: 
@Contract("_, null -> null") — method returns null if its second argument is 
null @Contract("_, null -> null; _, !null -> !null") — method returns null 
if its second argument is null and not-null otherwise @Contract("true -> 
fail") —atypical  assertFalse method which throws an exception if true is 
passed to it 
The inspection can be configured to use custom @Nullable @NotNull 
annotations (by default the ones from annotations.jar will be used)
```

Please forgive me if there are an typing errors in the error part:
Or here is a pic:
[image: Warning]

If you want to know - this is a modified app of the app samples from the android developers website. I know about the license this is just me testing the app.

Comment: post it here yourself and i will help you out with the edit part

Comment: I couldn't type it out cause stack overflow kept detecting that I hadn't formatted some code despite having done so. I apologize for this but please do help me.

Comment: use four spaces to let the editor know you are entering code. You will most likely have to indent each line, although not always. For `keywords`, put the `text in back ticks`

Comment: I tried it but it was not working. But Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final int CONTACT_QUERY_LOADER = 0;
    public static final String QUERY_KEY = "query";
    public EditText cn;
    String query = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        cn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mainEditText);
                startQuery();
    }

        private void startQuery()
                {
            query = cn.getText().toString();
            // We need to create a bundle containing the query string to    
    send along to the
            // LoaderManager, which will be handling querying the database
    and returning results.
                        if(query!="")
                        {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(QUERY_KEY, query);

            ContactablesLoaderCallbacks loaderCallbacks = new    
    ContactablesLoaderCallbacks(this);

            // Start the loader with the new query, and an object that will
    handle all callbacks.
            getLoaderManager().restartLoader(CONTACT_QUERY_LOADER, bundle,
    loaderCallbacks);
        }
                }
    }
```

Comment: BTW I also should have probably put in a button to handle the method. :) Silly me!. Will try and let you know. Thanks A LOT for your HELP! :)

Comment: Did it with the button and it works like a charm! :)